# Source control operation failed permission denied in IBM RTC

Tags: rtc, jazz

What can you do to understand why you see a "permission denied" in RTC, and what action to take in order to give the privilege for a given "denied" action?

Example:

[image: permission denied in RTC]

Comment: Its urgent If any one know this issue please help me to working...

Comment: Can you post the exact message and some details?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you have a permission denied on RTC, you need to check:

- your role associated with your profile in your project area
- your permissions as defined in "Team Configuration / Permission":

The permission matrix looks like this one in the Project Area Administration page:

[image: matrix]

For instance, if you have a "permission denied" when trying to delete a Work Item, you need to have a role where this action has been explicitly granted ([see doc](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.workitem.doc/topics/t_deleting_work_items.html&re=1&scope=null)):

[image: delete wi]

If you don't have access to the administration part, check at least the "**Team Advisor**" view in order to communicate that to your RTC admin:

[image: team advisor]

Comment: also, can you try to open that item in the webclient and see the (extensive) error message on top?