# Possibility of restoring a deleted stream?

Tags: rtc

A new stream called `stream 1` is created.
I deliver some changes to `stream 1`.

Later, I delete `stream 1`.

So:

- Is there a possibility to restore a deleted stream?
- If I am not able to restore the stream then, will I loose my changes delivered to it?

Comment: these two are qiuestions exactly

Comment: Yes, but you still haven't resolved (ie accepted) your past questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to restore a deleted stream?

Not easily unless you had created snapshots (we covered snapshots in your previous question "[Consistency of snapshot code in rtc?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38664034/6309)"): in that case, when you delete a stream, RTC would ask you to select another existing stream in order to keep ownership of those snapshots.
If you do, then it is trivial to re-create a new stream from a snapshot, assuring you to recover all components at their exact state as recorded by the snapshot.

But if you didn't set any snapshot, then you have to manually re-enter all the components, and set them to (for instance) their most recent baselines.

> If I am not able to restore the stream then, will I loose my changes delivered to it?

In any case, as mentioned in the thread "[Delete a Stream - any side-effects?](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/9022/delete-a-stream-any-side-effects)"

> Change-sets exist independently of any stream, so deleting a
> stream does not delete any change-sets.

It will just be harder to get the exact list of change sets back to a new stream if they were only delivered to `stream 1` (that you deleted).
Especially if those change set were never grouped inside a baseline (for a given component) or, as explained above, with a snapshot.
But those change sets are not gone.

Comment: If i delete a stream without creating a snap shot or baselining of a component then is there a possibility to get the changes ?

Comment: @user3302323 if you know from which repo workspace those change sets were coming from, you can accept them, and publish them yourself, as we discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38661956/6309 (that you did not yet accept). But this is certainly harder, because it supposes you know which change sets are involved and were delivered to that deleted stream.

Comment: Is there any  user control access to prevent the deletion of a stream?

Comment: @user3302323 Yes: each user is assigned a role, and permissions are associated with that role. In your case "Delete the stream
modify/stream/delete" under the "Save Stream" section. You can see that "Save Stream" section just above work Item in my other answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10364186/6309)

Comment: Yes i am able to see it. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @user3302323 You are most welcome. Don't forget to review your past questions though: I can complete them if needed.